# PHP how to create a default variable from a MySQL cursor that is empty

Tags: php, mysql, cursor

I have a cursor that returns empty when the row does not exist.
But I need to use the variable anyway to fill out a form and then eventually create the row.
But when I try to initialize the variable in the if-else section I get an error:
**Warning: Creating default object from empty value in /var/www/html/c.php on line 30.**
Is there a command that can be used to initialize a variable for this purpose so that I don't get an error?

```
$query_c = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE `cid` = ".$_SESSION['cid'];
$stmt_c = $dbh->query($query_c);
$row_c = $stmt_c->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

if ($rowcount>0) {
  $row_c->subject= str_replace("`","'",$row_c->subject);
  $row_c->textcontent = str_replace("`","'",$row_c->textcontent);
  $row_c->notes = str_replace("`","'",$row_c->notes);
} else {
  $row_c->subject = "";
  $row_c->textcontent = "";
  $row_c->notes = "";
}
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Check if `$row_c` is empty or not. If it is, create a new instance of [stdClass](https://www.php.net/manual/en/class.stdclass.php) and set all properties you expect to find with default values. `$row_c = new stdClass; $row_c->foo = 'some default';` and so on.

Answer (score 0):

Try using "'" or "‘" instead of "`"

```
$query_c = "SELECT * FROM content WHERE `cid` = " . $_SESSION['cid'];
$stmt_c = $dbh->query($query_c);
$row_c = $stmt_c->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

if ($rowcount > 0) { 
  $row_c->subject = str_replace("‘", "'", $row_c->subject);
  $row_c->textcontent = str_replace("‘", "'", $row_c->textcontent);
  $row_c->notes = str_replace("‘", "'", $row_c->notes);
} else {
  $row_c->subject = "";
  $row_c->textcontent = "";
  $row_c->notes = "";
}
```